# ASP.Net Caching with MemoryCache - null after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have been trying to use the System.Runtime.Caching MemoryCache object as shown below. When I debug I can see that it the cache is filled with the List of objects.  However, following a postback the cache is always null.  I thought the cache should persist until the expiration time was reached or the application was restarted. I must be missing something.

```
        public MemoryCache myCache = new MemoryCache("appCache");
    private const string myCacheKey = "appCache"; 
    public List<APPOINTMENT> Cache
    {
        get { return myCache[myCacheKey] as List<APPOINTMENT>; }
        set { myCache[myCacheKey] = value; }
    }
    public IEnumerable<APPOINTMENT> GetAllAppointmentsFor(string client)
    {
        CacheItemPolicy cachePolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();
        cachePolicy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2);

        myCache.Add(    myCacheKey,_uOW.APPOINTMENTs.GetAllAppointmentsFor(client).ToList(), cachePolicy);

        var ap = Cache as List<APPOINTMENT>;
        return ap;
    }
```

Comment: if you're using ASP.NET, use this cache: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache(v=vs.110).aspx  and btw, don't save a client data into the cache unless the cache is unique.  i.e., if you look at client A's appointments, then move to client B, you'll still get the appointments for client A from the cache because the key is the same.

Comment: the `MemoryCache` is instance-based, so that's why you're losing the data.  the variable goes out of scope at the end of the request.  if you have a singleton setup, you could probably get this working with a single instance, but you may be better off using the cache link I posted above.  `Another difference is that you can create multiple instances of the MemoryCache class for use in the same application and in the same AppDomain instance.`  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I am trying to avoid using the system.web.caching because I'm attempting to follow an MVP structure which excludes any references to ASP.NET libraries outside of the UI. I had no idea the MemoryCache would be lost so easily.  Is there any other caching that won't be disposed by a postback perhaps? Thanks again.

Comment: you could things like `MemCache`, `AppFabric`, `Redis`, etc.